# Longer LK4X Printer 3D touch sensor not contacting build plate on position 1

Tags: 3dtouch

I was trying to manual-level my printbed when the 3D Touch sensor quit contacting the build plate,causing the nozzle to crash into the print bed,how do i fix this(like it should be at y0 but its at negative y (x=0,y=0 is frontleft on my printer)

No changes have been made to the printer or model

Comment: What is your question? There are only statements with very few details.

Comment: Oh! I want to know how to fix this issue. It is preventing me from leveling the plate,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any and all information that could help in finding a solution. What firmware are you using? Did you update the firmware? Make any changes to the printer. Without further information, the question could be closed for lack of details.